# Как работает цепочка вызовов yield return в составных linq запросах?

Tags: linq

Какой результат выдадут запросы, я могу сказать, а как текут данные внутри одного составного запроса?

Comment: Вы бы хоть пример кода какой-то привели, чтобы не совсем умозрительно всё было. А так ну всё обычно будет наверное - "ленивое" исполнение. Пока кто-то не захочет результат, запрос будет строиться. Как захотят результат - дерево запросов оптимизируется и пойдёт исполнение. Дальше надо конкретику кода смотреть уже.

Comment: Книга "LINQ. Карманный справочник", Албахари. В первой части как раз рассказано про это.